# how to fixe occured errors after using entrust package with laravel

Tags: laravel, entrust

I followed a tutorial on how to use roles, permissions... with a laravel app. I am using entrust package
this the interface :

[image: Interface]

But, I am facing 2 errors, (i ll talk about both of them in the same topic, cause I thought maybe they caused by same thing) :

1) ErrorException in Gate.php line 317:
Illegal offset type in isset or empty

--> this happens when I click on "items" or "roles"

2) FatalErrorException in UserController.php line 88:
Call to a member function pluck() on null

--> It happens when I try to edit a user

This it Usercontroller :

```
 //....
public function edit($id)
{
    $user = User::find($id);
    $roles = Role::pluck('display_name','id');
    $userRole = $user->roles->pluck('id','id')->toArray();
    return view('users.edit',compact('user','roles','userRole'));
}

public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email,'.$id,
        'password' => 'same:confirm-password',
        'roles' => 'required'
    ]);

    $input = $request->all();
    if(!empty($input['password'])){ 
        $input['password'] = Hash::make($input['password']);
    }else{
        $input = array_except($input,array('password'));    
    }

    $user = User::find($id);
    $user->update($input);
    DB::table('role_user')->where('user_id',$id)->delete();


    foreach ($request->input('roles') as $key => $value) {
        $user->attachRole($value);
    }

    return redirect()->route('users.index')
                    ->with('success','User updated successfully');
}
```

and this is ItemController :

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'title' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required',
    ]);

    Item::create($request->all());

    return redirect()->route('itemCRUD2.index')
                    ->with('success','Item created successfully');
}

public function show($id)
{
    $item = Item::find($id);
    return view('ItemCRUD2.show',compact('item'));
}

public function edit($id)
{
    $item = Item::find($id);
    return view('ItemCRUD2.edit',compact('item'));
}
```

and this is RoleController :

```
  public function index(Request $request)
{
    $roles = Role::orderBy('id','DESC')->paginate(5);
    return view('roles.index',compact('roles'))
        ->with('i', ($request->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
}

public function create()
{
    $permission = Permission::get();
    return view('roles.create',compact('permission'));
}

public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required|unique:roles,name',
        'display_name' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required',
        'permission' => 'required',
    ]);

    $role = new Role();
    $role->name = $request->input('name');
    $role->display_name = $request->input('display_name');
    $role->description = $request->input('description');
    $role->save();

    foreach ($request->input('permission') as $key => $value) {
        $role->attachPermission($value);
    }

    return redirect()->route('roles.index')
                    ->with('success','Role created successfully');
 }

 public function show($id)
 {
    $role = Role::find($id);
    $rolePermissions = Permission::join("permission_role","permission_role.permission_id","=","permissions.id")
        ->where("permission_role.role_id",$id)
        ->get();

    return view('roles.show',compact('role','rolePermissions'));
 }
 public function edit($id)
 {
    $role = Role::find($id);
    $permission = Permission::get();
    $rolePermissions = DB::table("permission_role")->where("permission_role.role_id",$id)
        ->pluck('permission_role.permission_id','permission_role.permission_id');

  return view('roles.edit',compact('role','permission','rolePermissions'));
 }
```

the model : User.php

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
use Notifiable;

protected $table = 'users';
/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];
}
```

Could anyone help me to solve this ? thanks in advance.

Updates :

After changing the driver to array in my .env file.
CACHE_DRIVER=array I am getting this when clicking on items or roles. Trying to find out how to attribute roles to users now !!

[image]

Comment: Where is line 88 in the `UserController`?

Comment: @Jerodev this is it :    $userRole = $user->roles->pluck('id','id')->toArray();

Comment: Can you add the code for you user model?

Comment: I think that might be the problem, I didn't change the model, please see the post again, I edited it @Jerodev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the correct relations to your user model before you can load them. You are trying to load the property `roles` from you `User` model, but this doesn't exist so it returns `null`.

The `EntrustUserTrait` has to be added to your `User` model, as [defined here](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust#user).

Comment: This is working ! Thank you. One error has been solved.
To fixe the other one, I changed the driver to array in my .env file.
CACHE_DRIVER=array. Now when I click on roles or items I got the following message : You don't have permission as you can see in the image above. Now trying to find out how to attribute roles to users

Comment: You should change this in the database. Also, this is a second question, you should close this question and create a new one for the other question.